# pthread_setcanceltype workaround in android

Tags: android, c, pthreads, pthreads-win32

I am writing code for my first tool which supports multi threading but also I want to make my tool for both Linux & Android , and **pthread_cancel** can't be used in android so I am trying to make separate header file **universal-threading.h** in which I will declare **pthread_cancel** function for android.

So when it will compile on Android then **universals-threading.h** will be included otherwise not.

I made also a function of **pthread_setcancelstate** for android 
Here is snippet

```
static int pthread_setcancelstate(int state, int *oldstate) {
    sigset_t   new, old;
    int ret;
    sigemptyset (&new);
    sigaddset (&new, SIG_CANCEL_SIGNAL);

    ret = pthread_sigmask(state == PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE ? SIG_BLOCK : SIG_UNBLOCK, &new , &old);
    if(oldstate != NULL)
    {
        *oldstate = sigismember(old,SIG_CANCEL_SIGNAL) == 0 ? PTHREAD_CANCEL_DISABLE : PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

But now I am confused with pthread_setcanceltype function so it will be very helpful for me if you will give a working code block or snippet of pthread_setcanceltype android version .

**In short I want to create a fake pthread_setcanceltype function for android**

I am not professional its my first tool and I am also new to threading and pthreads so I hope you will consider this while answering me .

Comment: Design so that pthread_cancel() is not required.  There, job done.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you, can you please explain in brief :)

Comment: @Golu He is saying you should change your code so that you do not need to call `pthread_setcanceltype`. (Note that as Android does not natively support `pthread_setcanceltype` , it's pretty impossible for anyone here to come up with a version that will work on Android - you really need native support for it on the platform.)

Comment: I can see many projects in github which were ported to android by patching (adding fake setcancelstate  and pthread_cancel functions ) what about those ? And I am agree with you I should change my code for better future of my tool but just for knowledge I want to make a fake setcanceltype function and I am unable to find example on github because I found only few projects with fake pthread_setcancelstate but not setcanceltype.

Comment: @Golu long time after... Hope you found your answer. The code for `pthread_setcancelstate` is awesome thank you very much!